# how to print the full last index of List of products after if condition because its show 'instance of Product'

Tags: list, flutter, if-statement, dart

[the problem here in dart code][1]

how to print the full last index of List of products after if condition because its show 'instance of Product'
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeHYx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override `toString()` in the Product class and then when you print the object of the product then it will print the text which is return in the toString method.

Example:

```
class Product {
  int productId;
  String productName;
  
  Product(this.productId,this.productName);
  
  @override
  String toString(){
    return "\nProduct ID - $productId, Product name - $productName";
  }
}
void main() {
  List<Product> products= [];
  products.add(new Product(1, "Test Product1"));
  products.add(new Product(2, "Test Product2"));
  products.add(new Product(3, "Test Product3"));
  print(products);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the index of the last products
List in dart start with index 0, that means subtracting 1 from the total length of the list will give you the index of the last product

```
List<int> products = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];

print(products.length - 1); // 4 is the last index
```

To get the last item in the list,

```
print(products.last) // 6
```